# shopping cart array not rendering properly, react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fetch

after a fetch if I click to some card I am able to populate an empty array.
I would like to pass it as a prop to a child component and I guess I am doing the right way, the problem occurs when within the children I am trying to console log it because I can not see any errors and the console.log is not printing anything

---

```
let shoppingCart = [];

const fetchProducts = async () => {
const data = await fetch(
  "blablablablablab"
);
const products = await data.json();
setProducts(products);
console.log(products);
};


const handleShoppingCart = product => {
  shoppingCart.push(product);
  console.log(shoppingCart);
  return shoppingCart;
};
```

**Inside the return function I tried to check if the array was not empty, if was not undefined or if was not null but with the same result**

```
{shoppingCart.length !== 0 ? (
    <ShoppingCart parkingSlots={shoppingCart} />
  ) : null}
```

**children component**

```
const ShoppingCart = ({ parkingSlots }) => {
  console.log(parkingSlots);
  const parkingSlotsComponent = parkingSlots.map((parkingSlot, i) => {
  // const { name } = parkingSlot;
  return (
    <div className="parking_details" key={i}>
      {parkingSlot.name}
    </div>
  );
});
return <div className="checkout">{parkingSlotsComponent}</div>;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is in `props`.

When data is passed to child component via `props`, then it is part of props child component. Try below and see if you can console log the data.

```js
const ShoppingCart = props => {
  console.log(props.parkingSlots);
  const parkingSlotsComponent = props.parkingSlots.map((parkingSlot, i) => {
  // const { name } = parkingSlot;
  return (
    <div className="parking_details" key={i}>
      {props.parkingSlot.name}
    </div>
  );
});
return <div className="checkout">{parkingSlotsComponent}</div>;
 };
```

Comment: nothing at all but again with no errors, so if do some check with ternary operator in order to return the child component with props in some cases it will return the child empty array first and then the fetched array of the parent and makes sense that I can not print it out but how to avoid this?

Comment: `shoppingCart.length !== 0` Do you have any data in the `shoppingCart` at first place?

Comment: No I first initiate it as empty array and then push item inside it once clicked on single card, I can see it is populating by console.log and then try to pass it to the child component